# Remove border before last cell

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple table, styled with bootstrap, with 3 columns and a few rows (dynamically added with data from the server).

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>Data</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th><!-- Should be 'Edit' but I'm hiding it--></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td width="70px"><a href="/link/to/edit/value">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to remove the border between the columns `Value` and `Edit` to make it looks like it is one column.

This is what I've tried :

```
<style>
    th:last-child, td:last-child {
        border-left: none !important;
    }
    th:nth-last-child(2), td:nth-last-child(2) {
        border-right:none !important;
    }
</style>
```

It's actually working but I don't want to use the `!important` parameter.

Is there a way to do this without `!important`, or another way to put both information in the same cell like this : `Value` info in the middle of the cell, and `Edit` info on the right ?

---

**Edit**
Thank you [Aaron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1676224/aaron) for giving me the [without !important way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37349126/4864023) which is :

```
<style>
    body table.table.table-bordered tr th:last-child,
    body table.table.table-bordered tr td:last-child {
        border-left: none;
    }

    body table.table.table-bordered tr th:nth-last-child(2),
    body table.table.table-bordered tr td:nth-last-child(2) {
        border-right: none;
    }
</style>
```

Even if it works well, I am sure there is a better way to do it like an `inline` way. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a style set you can make the tag specifity higher by using the classes and tags.

so your style will become like this:

```
<style>
    body table.table.table-bordered tr th:last-child, td:last-child {
        border-left: none;
    }
    body table.table.table-bordered tr th:nth-last-child(2), 
    body table.table.table-bordered tr td:nth-last-child(2) {
        border-right:none;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: It also works, but I'm looking for a way to do that without using `!important` tag

Comment: @tektiv sorry i left those by mistake, see the updated version

Comment: Brillant ! It works well, I just had to replace `td:last-child` from the first style rule with `body table.table.table-bordered tr td:last-child`. Thank you !

Comment: no problem @tektiv, for your future reference including more tags and classes will hold a higher priority over a style on the same element without the extra classes. Forinstance just adding 'body' before a class can make the class more specific.

Comment: @tektiv if you could mark my answer as correct when you get a chance please.

Comment: Thanks for the Css lesson, I didn't know that. The thing is, I'm sur there is a better to do it, like in only one cell and in order to put `Value` information right in the middle. For the moment, you can see it has an offset to the left from the middle, which is quite ugly. Post updated btw

Answer (score 0):

Css = Cascading style sheets,
if you load your

```
th:last-child, td:last-child {
    border-left: none !important;
}
```

before the twitter bootstrap, it gets overwritten unless its '!important'
try load your style after the bootstrap loading and it shouldn't get overwritten - no more !important !

your only other option would be inline css?

Comment: It is an internal style tag, which is loaded after bootstrap. So it can't be the problem. How can I use inline css in this case ?

Comment: inline css over-writes the sheet or <style></style> rules
inline looks like this: <div style="top=kekpx;"></div> Inline css does not support many selectors and compex actions.
I'm glad you found a solution :)

Answer (score -1):

to put the information in the same cell, you could use

```
<tr>
    <th>Data</th>
    <th>Value | Edit</th>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td width="70px">
        <span style="float:left;width:50%;">this is the left</span>
        <span style="float:right;width:50%:">this is right</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

you can use the bootstrap .text-center class in the first span element to align the text in the middle. Hope it helps.

Comment: As a span isn't a block element, adding a width has no effect.